# Fatal javascript error after logging in to phpmyadmin on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Previously, phpmyadmin was working fine. Haven't used it for a while lately.

> Version information: 5.1.1deb5ubuntu1

I log in to phpmyadmin on this laptop.

> http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/

I see my database, but at the bottom are some nasty red messages:

> A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error
> report?

There is a button to click: Show report details.

If I click the button, I get more messages as above, but nothing opens.

I cannot access any of the tables, I just see a whirring mouse type symbol and the message Loading, which doesn't stop.

I can access my database from the mysql command line, open a table, display data, so I don't think MySQL is the problem.

Any tips please?

I tried a different browser with the same result:

> A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error
> report?